# How can I resize an image in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Actually, I know how to resize an image in Python Tkinter. The only problem is, when I try to, it says AttributeError: `module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ANTIALIAS'`

```
varmakerIcon = Image.open("Varmaker ICON/varmaker-logo.png")
resized = varmakerIcon.resize((300, 150), Image.ANTIALIAS) # Problem is here
converted_image = PhotoImage(resized)

side_image = Label(password, image=converted_image)

label = Label(password, text="Enter Password:", font=("Calibri", 12))
label.pack()
```

Now what causes the error? I don't know. I have Pillow installed (pip install Pillow).
I tried it with ImageTk, I tried it without Image or ImageTk (it was not defined of course).
Please help if you can.

I tried to make my password verification window a side image of my logo to make it look better and cooler, but it didn't expectedly work due to a questionable error.

Comment: The values for the second argument are changed in later version of `Pillow`.  You should read the offical [document](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)